# Docker Laravel: Redirecting to https

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx

So I am trying to `dockerize` my existing `laravel` application. Here is what I am doing.

The `dir` structure is like this:

```
phirater-l51
  .. <laravel applciation>
  Dockerfile
docker
  mysql
    init
      01-databases.sql
    my.cnf
  nginx
    default.conf
  docker-compose.yml
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  app:
    container_name: app
    build:
      args:
        user: ${USER}
        uid: ${UID}
      context: ./../phirater-l51
      dockerfile: ./../phirater-l51/Dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www/
    environment:
      - COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phirater-l51:latest
    volumes:
      - ./../phirater-l51:/var/www
    networks:
      - phios

  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: db
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
      - ./mysql/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    networks:
      - phios

  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - "8005:80"
    depends_on:
      - app
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./../phirater-l51:/var/www
      - ./nginx/:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    networks:
      - phios

  cache:
    container_name: cache
    image: redis:alpine
    volumes:
      - cachedata:/data
    networks:
      - phios

networks:
  phios:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
  cachedata:
    driver: local
```

Here is my nginx/default.conf file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/public;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }
}
```

Now when I run the containers it works fine but when I try to do curl localhost:8005 from terminal it returns this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='https://localhost:8005'" />

        <title>Redirecting to https://localhost:8005</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Redirecting to <a href="https://localhost:8005">https://localhost:8005</a>.
    </body>
</html>
```

When I do curl -I, I get these headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx/1.25.1
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.4.33
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Date: Thu, 20 Jul 2023 06:44:34 GMT
Location: https://localhost:8005
Set-Cookie: laravel_session=<session>; path=/; secure; httponly
```

And when I try to do it in browser I get this:

> This site can’t provide a secure connectionlocalhost sent an invalid

> response. ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: your nginx doesn't `listen 443 ssl;` so maybe u have only to change your .env file. from https to http. `APP_URL=http://localhost`. 
nginx example for https: 
`listen 443 ssl;
listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/default.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/default.key;`

Comment: @JayDee So as this is localhost, I dont want https, so no related config in nginx. As for APP_URL goes, you mean in the env of the application, right?

Comment: yes .env from your laravel-application :)

Comment: @JayDee I have already tried `APP_URL=http://localhost` but to no effect. It still redirects to https.

Comment: maybe a cache clear would help .. `php artisan config:clear` .. sry no ideas anymore ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Laravel in a custom docker as well.  Here an working example of my NGINX config for `http`. Works fine without redirect. `http://project.test/`

It's pretty close to the official Laravel suggestion: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/deployment#nginx

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name project.test;

    root /var/www/laravel/public;
    index index.php;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

You have several deviations like no `server_name`.
Try to add it.

Or pick the official config and check if the problem is gone. After that you can adjust the working config until you reach your goal or the problem.

Comment: I've tried the exact same config as you posted but I still get the same issue. Its still redirecting to https.

Comment: btw I tried a fresh laravel installation and the same config worked fine.

Comment: good to hear, that you have a working solution now